# Bash script to kill a process if process count is over X amount

Tags: php, bash, process, kill

So, I was wondering if there was a way to see if one could use bash to kill a PID of a process if more than X amount spawned. For example:

Let's say we have 10 php processes running with separate PIDs all with the command /usr/bin/php. If it hit 10 processes, would there be a way to kill it with a bash script?
(I'll be having this script run full time in the foreground with a terminal)

Comment: not sure I understood correctly. You want to kill the 10th /usr/bin/php process as it comes to live? Or you want to kill all 10 processes? And, sorry, WTF are you doing it?

Comment: As the website I'm hosting is on a shared server (with jailshell enabled), there's a process limit of 25 processes total. This is an experiment to see if it can be limited to 10 processes. I specifically would like it to kill all php processes (ps afux| grep php | grep -v "grep"| awk '{print $2}') if it hits 10 processes on the list.

Comment: belongs in unix.stackexchange dont you think?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you're solving the wrong problem. I'd rather make sure that the process in itself couldn't have more than one instance ([here's an implementation checklist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14750/stop-parallel-processing-for-a-cron-triggered-process)), and give instructions by some sort of instruction stack.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea to kill stuff this way, but this is what you asked.
Try with this one (all on one single line):

```
j=0; for i in `ps fax | grep '/usr/bin/php'  | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`; do let j=j+1; if [ $j -ge 10 ]; then echo "Killing process $i"; kill $i; fi done
```

Pay attention to what you are doing.
HTH.

Comment: you need to put it in crontab running once a minute, or hack it a little bit to let it running into an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, the crontabs are limited too (by once every 15 minutes) =\

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

#PROGRAM_NAME=/usr/bin/php
PROGRAM_NAME="gedit"
MAX_INSTANCES=2
CURRENT_INSTANCES=0

while true
do
    sleep 1
    let CURRENT_INSTANCES=`ps aux | grep -c $PROGRAM_NAME`
    if [ "$CURRENT_INSTANCES" -ge "$MAX_INSTANCES" ];then
        killall $PROGRAM_NAME
        echo "killing program!"
        exit 0;
    fi
done
```

Comment: Note that the `grep` you have will find itself (and similarly-named commands to the target).  My answer below has a more precise count, assuming the target command is a simple name and not a full path/command line.  
   In general, that's a very old-school Bourne-style script; outside of the `let` (and you aren't taking advantage of the variable's integerness), you could replace the bash shebang line with `#!/bin/sh` and run it most anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
program_name=php
let max_instances=10
let poll_interval=60

while true; do 
  if (( count=$(ps -eocomm | grep -c "^$program_name$") > max_instances )); then
    killall "$program_name"
    echo "Found $count $program_name processes. Killed."
  fi
  sleep "$poll_interval"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

When you kill php processes, you also kill client connections, which might result in unsatisfied customers and lost revenue.

If you're running an apache web server, you can limit the number of http servers/client connections and so the number of php processes.

Look into your apache conf file and look out for:

```
StartServers
MinSpareThreads
MaxSpareThreads
ThreadLimit
ThreadsPerChild
MaxClients
MaxRequestsPerChild
```

Depending on how your PHP processes are startet (suphp, fcgi, ...) there might be other options as well.

Other web servers provide similar settings.